# `gcloud app deploy` throws `No module named 'main'` when I move my main Flask python file into a module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple Flask app, consisting of a single file, `main.py`.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world."
```

I also have one other file in the project directory, `app.yaml`, which consists of a single line:

```
runtime: python37
```

If I run `gcloud app deploy` on this or flask run, the page is rendered correctly both on google cloud and locally, displaying a page that reads "Hello world."

However, if I move `main.py` to `./app/__init__.py`, `gcloud app deploy` no longer renders the page (even though `flask run` still functions correctly!) giving me a 502 Bad Gateway error. The log gives the error:

```
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
__import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'"
```

Any ideas on what the problem is here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not define `entrypoint` in your YAML file, [App Engine will configure and start the Gunicorn webserver.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup)

The default configuration provided by GCloud is:

```
gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Therefore you need to configure the [entrypoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#entrypoint) field if your entrypoint is not `main.py`